# Django - ajax poll with results on the same page

Tags: ajax, django, redirect

I'm learning django and I need help with my app.
In a page I have a poll: I want that after a user has voted,  the poll form disappears and a div #ajaxresults appears with the updated votes for each option.
I'm using an ajax call but I can't return the updated votes.

If I call directly '/polls/4/results' I can see the right list but I can't include that block on the same page of the form.
What am I missing?

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='list'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**view.py**

```
def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    #return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
    return redirect(question.get_absolute_url())

@require_POST
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['selectionId'])
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return redirect('polls:results', question_id = question_id)
```

**detail template** (extends base.html)

```
<form id="quiz-module" action="#">
 <input type="hidden" id="pollId" name="pollId" value="{{question.id}}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <h2>{{ question.question_text }}</h2>
        <ul>
        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
            <li><input type="radio" name="opt" value="{{ choice.id }}" {% if forloop.first %}required {%endif%}/>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<section id="quiz-results">
    <h3>Your vote</h3>
    <p id="ajaxresults"></p>
    <h3>All votes</h3>
    <dl>
        {%block updated_results %}{% endblock %}
    </dl>
</section>
```

**template vote** is empty

**template results** (extends nothing)

```
{%block updated_results %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <dt>{{ choice.choice_text }}:  </dt><dd id="choiceId-{{ choice.id }}">{{ choice.votes }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

js

```
var args = { 
                type:"POST", 
                url:"/polls/"+pollId+"/vote/", 
                data:data, 
                success: function( data ) {
                    //print your vote
                    results.children('#ajaxresults').html(selectionText); 
                    form.hide('fast');
                    results.show('fast');
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  alert(error+'<br/>'+"Sorry. Can't submit your vote. Please, reload the page and try again")
                },
            };
            $.ajax(args);
```

Comment: Where do you call the `results` url on your JS?

Comment: You're right. I have changed the vote view with 'return redirect('polls:results', question_id = question_id)'  but in the end the 'updated_results' block is still missing

Comment: I'm on mobile atm, but by a quick look, it seems like you're not rendering the template with your results in the end nor including the updated_results block; you need an async view that grabs the template called `results`, populates it and returns the rendered version; then, your ajax script should catch that outputed html and replace the content of your `<dl></dl>` block (without you needing to define a `{% block ... %}`)

Comment: Hi Samuele, thanks. Walucas' comment has put me on the right track yesterday.  I was confused about the template inheritance but now I understand it a little better. In the end, I include {% include "polls/results.html" %} inside detail.html. The vote view calls the results page, the results page goes back to the poll but to show it I need to include it.
Thanks everybody for all your kindly help, can you suggest an example of async ajax call?